# what does "crafting" mean in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning, idioms

From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nirvana_(band)

> Later when Nirvana recorded Bleach, Cobain felt he had to fit the
>   expectations of the Sub Pop grunge sound to build a fanbase, and hence
>   suppressed his arty and pop songwriting traits **while crafting the
>   record in favor of a more rocking sound**.

Can someone explain the bold part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, 'crafting' means 'fashioning' or 'creating'. In addition, I think your bold text indicates how you are interpreting the phrases in the sentence, and I personally read the sentence differently, which I have restructured to remove ambiguity:

> Later when Nirvana recorded Bleach, Cobain felt he had to fit the expectations of the Sub Pop grunge sound to build a fanbase, and hence **while crafting the record, suppressed his arty and pop songwriting traits in favor of a more rocking sound**.